# Why doesn't python/pil save a 2d array filled with FF as a completely white bmp image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The below python/pillow code creates a 150x150 array and populates it with 255/FF before saving it as a bmp. But the image that is saved is not a white bmp as expected. Instead, it looks like a black image dotted with whites. Why is that?

```
c = [[(255, 255, 255)]*150 for i in range(150)]
ci = 0
cj = 0
for ci in range(150):
    for cj in range(150):
        c[ci][cj] = (255, 255, 255) #Also tried with 0/255 transparency and in hex etc.
c_array = np.asarray(c)
im2 = Image.fromarray(c_array, mode="RGB")
im2.save("test.bmp")
```

Image created (white dots on black instead of being completely white) -

[image]

and its hex version shows that somehow not all the FFs made it into the bmp - [image]

Why this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Since your input type is `int`, `c_array` will store your data as int32 (or int64, see numpy's [default behavior for `int`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)).

```
>>> c = [[(255, 255, 255)]*150 for i in range(150)]
>>> c_array = np.asarray(c)
>>> c_array.dtype
dtype('int32')
```

When imported in `Image.fromarray`, `c_array` is considered as a bytestring of `int8` since you specified `mode="RGB"` [(3x8-bit pixels)](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray). Since each element is an int32, the bytestring for each value is `\xff\x00\x00\x00`, thus creating the image you see.

The simpler correction would be to specify the type of the numpy array:

```
c_array = np.asarray(c, dtype=np.uint8)
```